# Relation between $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ for different primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, number-fields, absolute-galois-group

Let $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ denote the absolute Galois group of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. Also, their structure as abstract groups is completely known.

It is well known that this group embeds into the absolute Galois group of the rationals, $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

My question is: are there any known relations between the two absolute Galois groups of two $p$-adic fields, say $\mathbb{Q}_{p_1}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_{p_2}$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are different primes, regarded as subgroups of the absolute Galois group of the rationals?

Comment: The embedding $G_{\mathbf{Q}_p}\to $G_{\mathbf{Q}}$, if I'm correct, is only defined up to conjugation, and in particular its image is only well-defined up to conjugation.

Comment: I think it is known that the (closed) subgroup generated by finitely many of these is the (profinite) free product of these. If this is the kind of result you are interested in, I can look it up.

Comment: Yeah, I am precisely curious about this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the remarks above, there are different (although conjugate) embeddings $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}\rightarrow G_\mathbb{Q}$. Let us fix one of them and denote its image by $G_p$.

If we fix prime numbers $p_1,\dots,p_n$ (not necessarily distinct), then
the set of $\sigma=(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n)\in G_\mathbb{Q}^n$ for which the closed subgroup
$\left< G_{p_1}^{\sigma_1},\dots,G_{p_n}^{\sigma_n}\right>$ is the profinite free product of $G_{p_1},\dots,G_{p_n}$ has Haar measure $1$.
This is (a special case of) Theorem 4.1 in W.-D. Geyer, Galois groups of intersection of local fields, Israel Journal of Mathematics 30, 1978.

Geyer also notes in section 4.4 that one cannot expect this to hold for *every* $\sigma$, but his example is for archimedean places. A purely group theoretic result of Haran occurring as Proposition 4.2.3 in Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg's Cohomology of Number Fields however shows that also for non-archimedean places it does not hold for *every* $\sigma$.